# BigCommerce - Custom Checkout (Adding Field to Cart)

Tags: bigcommerce

I am doing some work for a client who uses BigCommerce Stencil Theme and I am pretty new to BC. Until now most of my work with them has been basic theme formatting and styling.

They are asking if I can add checkboxes next to items in cart to indicate an alternative delivery system, and then add a field to address for a hotel room. It seems like built into BC checkout customization you can add fields to addresses so that doesn't seem like an issue, but I'm not so sure about the checkboxes. I would imagine I would need access to the underlying PHP to make this happen which doesn't seem possible. Is this accurate? If not, how might I go about doing this?

I see that I can add the checkboxes themselves to the template files, but as far as sending any data with the checkout I don't know how I'd go about doing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the hotel room address field, you are correct that the simplest solution would be to use the built-in custom address field feature.

For the checkbox/alternate delivery system, we're close to releasing a new Checkout JS SDK that will give you the ability to create a completely custom checkout experience. The SDK is basically a Javascript wrapper for our Storefront Checkout API and it includes operations for checkout actions (like creating a new shipping consignment for an alternate delivery method).

The Checkout SDK doesn't give you access to the underlying PHP; instead, it allows you to create your own frontend using React or whatever framework you prefer. The logic for custom checkout steps would exist in your frontend, and you would send your data to the checkout via the BC Checkout API.

https://stencil.bigcommerce.com/docs/customizing-checkout

Comment: Thanks for the info! Do you know when it will be released? One of the issues I'm facing is I did not develop the theme they are using so I can't edit the JS. Is there a workaround for this?

Comment: I don't have an ETA just yet, but I can follow up in this thread when we set a release date. When you say you can't edit the JS because you didn't develop the theme, do you mean you aren't able to edit the theme locally using Stencil CLI? Could you elaborate on that a bit?

Comment: @KarenWhite can we extend one of Shipping option with checkout sdk instead of create new checkout with SDK?

Comment: @MuhammadUsama The Checkout SDK is intended to be used for creating a complete checkout replacement--not really to modify a single step of checkout. We're working on some solutions this year though that should give you more of a starting point if you only want to modify the Shipping step.

Comment: Could you please guide how we can create new shipping method through BigCommerce app?

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by create a new shipping method? Also, let's move this to a new question since it's not related to the OP :)

Comment: @KarenWhite posted a new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55346169/bigcommerce-custom-shipping-method-royalmail-widget-for-collect-location?noredirect=1#comment97417957_55346169